# dual boot on legacy bios, is it possible?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, google-chrome, bios

i have a old hp computer, which i installed chrome os and then installed ubuntu (followed online guide, hoping to dual boot), the problem is i don't get boot option on start up. I can install only Ubuntu and call it a day, but im curious about weather i can somehow dual boot on a legacy. BTW i'm totally a noob.  Please guide me to dual boot my pc.

what happens when i boot my pc- On start up i get booted to chrome os. And i cant find any much help regarding bios setting(or i dont know weather im doing 
 right or wrong).

Comment: Answer: Yes.
Is it easy: Most of the time, if its not a laptop.

Comment: no it is not a laptop, its a old pc.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can dualboot if you have grub. You will need to shrink and create a partition on the boot drive and install Ubuntu alongside chrome(installing chrome first). During installation Ubuntu might ask if you want to install Ubuntu alongside chrome. Choose this option and you should have a successful dualboot with grub.

Comment: well i ticked the "something else" option and then installed(according to some post online which i don't remember).
Q1: Should i go back and reinstall using the ubuntu alongside chrome option.
Q2: what is Grub?? how does it work?

sorry i have have little knowledge about computers.

Comment: GRUB is a bootloader that starts up when you turn on your computer. It lets you choose which operating system to boot to in startup. If you don't have anything valuable on Ubuntu, I would try reinstalling alongside chrome just to see if it works.

Comment: I have to cause i think i lost Ubuntu, because i don't know how to log in. every time i start the computer i get directly logged into chrome os.